# Read data from HTML Select Tag before sending to PHP

Tags: php, html

I need to send a  option to a PHP script, but the instead of a user clicking on a submit button, they simply click a  type link.

For instance:

```html
<select name="test">
   <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
<a href="next.php">Next</a>
```

So the user will select 1, then click on the link that says "Next".  It's almost like i need to read the select tag BEFORE sending it to the php by a GET request (php.php?select=1).  Any ideas how I can pass over this roadblock?

Comment: Jquery,javascript. have for you to serve

Comment: Link don't send data from form to server. Use `submit` input/button.

Comment: Look at jQuery to add an 'on change' action that will grab the selected value of 'test' and adjust `href="next.php"` into `href="next.php?test=1"`. In next.php you can grab the value by using `$_GET['test']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You Have to use `<form>` tag to make this possible or use ajax submit tu submit your form with `<form>` you can do in this way

```
<form action="next.php" method="POST">
 <select name="test">
   <option value="1">1</option>
 </select>
 <!-- Then after this don't use anchor tag <a> use input submit instead-->
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Next"/>
</form>
```

Or you can also submit it with `<button>` :

```
<form action="next.php" method="POST">
 <select name="test">
   <option value="1">1</option>
 </select>
 <!-- Then after this don't use anchor tag <a> use button instead-->
<button type="submit">Next</button>
</form>
```

as you mentioned in question you want to get the value of select before submit to php you can use `jQuery ajax` to do this look below

```
<form id="my_form" action="">
 <select id="my_tag" name="test">
   <option value="1">1</option>
 </select>
<button type="submit">Next</button>
</form>
```

Ajax:

```
$('#my_form').submit(function(e){
   if($('#my_tag').val() !== '') {
    var select = $('#my_tag').val();
    $.ajax({
         type: 'Get', // Could be GET/POST
         url: 'php.php?select='+select, //targeting url with value from select tag
         success: function(data){
         alert(data); // alerting the data which php file returned.
         }
     });
    } else {
       alert('error'); // if select tag is empty we will show an error.
    }
e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thanks!  I ended up just changing some things after realizing I couldn't do it the way I set it up.  This helped!