# How to get data from select tag using AJAX before submitting into PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to get the data of the select tag id="departmentselect" so that the values of it will be stored in the mysql database before submitting the form. I heard that you will use AJAX to get the data before you submit the form. Because when I select the College select tag and its corresponding values of the department select tag it will only store a number in the department of the database.

Example MYSQL database:
[image]

In the query of mysql, the department did not get the values of the JSON file. It only display the number.

Here is my **PHPCode**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<form action="SignupProcess.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return check_password();" id="signupform">
    <select id="collegeselect" name="collegeselect">
      <option value="">College</option>
      <option value="College of CAS">College of CAS</option>
    </select>

    <select id="departmentselect" name="departmentselect">
        <option value="">Department</option>
    </select>
</form>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="GetCollegeJsonData.js"></script>
<script>
        $('#signupform').submit(function(e))
        {
            if($('#departmentselect').val() != '')
            {
                $ajax
                ({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'Signup.php?select' += select,
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        alert(data);
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                alert('error');
            }
            e.preventDefault();
        });
</script>
</html>
```

**Script Type**
Here is the script for using ajax but it did not seem to have any effect.

```
<script>
        $('#signupform').submit(function(e))
        {
            if($('#departmentselect').val() != '')
            {
                $ajax
                ({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'Signup.php?select' += select,
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        alert(data);
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                alert('error');
            }
            e.preventDefault();
        });
</script>
```

**JQUERY Code** file name **GetCollegeJsonData.js**

I get the JSON data from the file and read it into my Jquery file and then link the file using script to my php code

```
//Get json
$('body').on('change', '#collegeselect', function() {
    var selected_college = $(this).val();

    $('#departmentselect').html('');

    $.getJSON("CollegeAndDepartment.json", function(data) {
        $.each(data[selected_college], function(key, val) {
            $('#departmentselect').append("<option value='" + key + "'>" + val + "</option>");
        });
    });
})
```

Its **JSON File**

```
{
    "College of CAS": ["Biology", "English", "LIACOM", "Library & Information Science", "Mass Communication", "Philosophy", "Political Science", "Psychology"]
}
```

Is my Ajax function is incorrect?

Comment: You miss the dot(`.`). It should be `$.ajax` not `$ajax`.

Comment: it still displays a number 0 in the department sir, I think my ajax function is incorrect.

Comment: It seems like there are a few syntax errors in here, which may not be the actual error but does potentially prevent others from properly identifying your problem. For example, Shiyou mentioned `$.ajax` when your question uses `$ajax`. I'm looking at `url: 'Signup.php?select' += select` .. what is happening here? What is the `select` variable?

Comment: I call the id="departmentselect" select tag sir and it means it targets the url  with value from the select tag. I use this link for reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30680554/read-data-from-html-select-tag-before-sending-to-php

Comment: You don't ever actually store the variable `select` though. You only grab the value for comparison in your `if` conditional: `if($('#departmentselect').val() != '')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have edited your code as below.

```
Kindly give it a try.

 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Sample</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="SignupProcess.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return check_password();" id="signupform">
        <select id="collegeselect" name="collegeselect">
          <option value="">College</option>
          <option value="College of CAS">College of CAS</option>
        </select>

        <select id="departmentselect" name="departmentselect">
            <option value="">Department</option>
        </select>
    </form>
    </body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="GetCollegeJsonData.js"></script>
    <script>
            $('#signupform').submit(function(e)
            {
                if($('#departmentselect').val() != '')
                {
                    $.ajax
                    ({
                        type: 'POST',
                        data:{select:$('#departmentselect').val()},
                        url: 'Signup.php',
                        success: function(data)
                        {
                            alert(data);
                        }
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    alert('error');
                }
                e.preventDefault();
            });


    </script>
    </html>

    For GetCollegeJsonData.js, ihave modified as follows:

    //Get json
    $('#collegeselect').on('change', function() {

        var selected_college = $(this).val();

        $('#departmentselect').html('');

        $.getJSON("CollegeAndDepartment.json", function(data) {
            $.each(data[selected_college], function(key, val) {
                $('#departmentselect').append("<option value='" + val + "'>" + val + "</option>");
            });
        });
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

Your ajax method code has syntax error and, when you use post method you have to post data using data option not with URL. data should be in json object or query string.
Your ajax function should be

```
<script>
        $('#signupform').submit(function(e))
        {
            if($('#departmentselect').val() != '')
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'Signup.php',
                    data: {select: $('#departmentselect').val()},
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        alert(data);
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                alert('error');
            }
            e.preventDefault();
        });
</script>
```

Comment: It will only display the value number of the department sir, not the values of the json file. Example: Select College of Cas, then you select English. When submitting the form, the value 'English' won't appear in the database. it will only display a value 0 or 1. The type is text in mysql.

Comment: It work sir, I did not realize that my query type of the department select tag is an int type.